# How to create a variable which can be accessed globally -oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE cost_proportion(
    p_assignment_id IN NUMBER,
    p_proportion    IN NUMBER,
    p_old_value     IN NUMBER,
    p_cost_alloc_id IN NUMBER,
    p_cost_code     IN VARCHAR2,
     p_date_from in date,
    p_flag IN VARCHAR2 )
IS
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  v_flag NUMBER :=0;

BEGIN

  IF p_flag = 'V' 
  THEN
    --            IF p_old_value > 0 THEN

            DELETE
            FROM cost_temp
            WHERE 1=1
               and cost_code = p_cost_code
              --AND
            AND assignment_id = p_assignment_id;



    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
          DELETE
          FROM cost_temp
          WHERE cost_allocation_id = p_cost_alloc_id
          AND assignment_id        = p_assignment_id;
    END IF;
    --            END IF;
    INSERT
    INTO cost_temp VALUES
      (
        p_assignment_id,
        p_proportion,
        p_old_value,
        p_cost_alloc_id,
        p_cost_code,
        p_flag
      );
    COMMIT;
  ELSIF p_flag = 'P' THEN
    DELETE FROM ecost_temp WHERE assignment_id = p_assignment_id;
    INSERT INTO cost_temp
          SELECT assignment_id,
            proportion * 100,
            0,
            cost_allocation_id,
            b.segment1
            || '|'
            || b.segment3
            || '|'
            || b.segment2
            || '|'
            || b.segment4
            || '|'
            || b.segment6,
            p_flag
          FROM pay_cost_allocations_f a,
            pay_cost_allocation_keyflex b
          WHERE a.cost_allocation_keyflex_id = b.cost_allocation_keyflex_id
          AND a.assignment_id                = p_assignment_id
          AND sysdate BETWEEN a.effective_start_date AND a.effective_end_date;

    COMMIT;


  ELSIF p_flag = 'D' THEN
        DELETE
        FROM cost_temp
        WHERE cost_code = p_cost_code
        AND proportion  = p_proportion;
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END;
```

In the above query I want that whenever the  p_flag = 'P' section is executed , a variable value is set .. this should be fixed value which i can access the next time i run this procedure. is this possible ?

say for example : v_flag=2 when p_flag='P' is executed.

and when again this procedure is called by a different block this value remains v_flag=2

Comment: You have to put your procedure in a package and declare global variables on the package body outside of any procedures or functions. That way the global variable will persists for the duration of the session.

Comment: or if you cannot use packages for unknown reason, you can store this flag in a table and everytime you enter to this section you update the flag and when you exit the procedure you update the flag back.

Comment: Are you talking about a single session calling the procedure again and again? Or do you even want the flag to be persistent cross-session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PL/SQL a global variable can only exist in a package. That's because PL/SQL initialises procedure level variables each time a procedure is called. Only a package allows us to define a variable outside of procedure scope.

This toy package will persist the value of `n` across multiple calls to `gvar_test.incr()`.

```
create or replace package gvar_test as
     procedure incr (p_in in number, p_out out number);
end gvar_test; 
/
create or replace package body gvar_test as
     n pls_integer;

     procedure incr (p_in in number, p_out out number) is
     begin
         n := n + p_in;
         p_out := n;
     end incr;
begin
    -- initialise variable first time package is called 
    n := 0;
end gvar_test; 
/
```

Global variables are a tricky thing. Many people regard their use as bad practice, primarily because it's very easy to lose track of state. This is particularly true when we're working with web apps going through a connection pool. PL/SQL variables are held in session memory, so are useless for persisting state across calls in an environment where each call can be handed off to a random session. In that case you should use Global Application Contexts to hold the value. These are accessible across database sessions (so you need to be careful about identifiers). [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/app_context.htm#DBSEG203).

Beyond that, consider whether in-memory variables (whether PL/SQL or Application Context) is a safe approach. If you're tracking some workflow or process state it would usually be better to store that in a table, if only for recovery purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You have database all around Your procedure - if You really need something like the count of executions of some block inside the procedure, just create dedicated table and update it with every execution.

The implementation will slightly vary if You cont executions in scope of individual transaction, in scope of session or it is overall count of executions...